# SIM800l power-up problems

Tags: voltage-regulator, lithium-ion, gsm

The datasheet of the SIM800l claims that currents can peak to around 2A during SIM registration and other network intensive activities. I tried powering up the module with the 5v output of a FTDI-USB converter plugged into my laptop (With a SIM inserted in the module),then regulated to around 3.4v using a LM1117 reg. But the module only restarted itself every 10 seconds or so without avail. Then i tried a NOKIA BL-5C (3.7v Li-Ion, 1080maH) and the module managed to get registered onto the network and I could use the GPRS commands. But now I will be designing the whole system onto a PCB with only a single input, that of a 5V, (1 or 2) Amp adapter. So, how can i efficiently power the SIM module? Can I use diodes in series with the 5v input to drop the voltage to around 4.3 v? Will that reduce the max current supply to the SIM module?

Comment: You can't.  Your input power is simply not sufficient, or at least not without local storage of a fairly substantial amount of energy.  Further, it going to be non-trivial to find a regulator with a sufficiently low dropout under this magnitude of load.  Your module was *originally* designed to be a "feature" phone, and as a result it wants a phone battery.

Comment: Ok anything you can tell me if it can be done using diodes? By dropping voltage around them and hence effectively reducing the voltage? Does that affect current?

Comment: Diodes won't solve the problem of needing far more power than the half amp you are supplying at the input.  Only more power input, possibly if the demand is pulses enough large capacitors to time average it to a lower value, or better yet the battery it is *designed* to run from will solve that.

Comment: OMG I'm so sorry that 1/2 Amp I specified meant 1 OR 2 amps. Sorry, my bad!

Comment: 1 or 2 amps is not enough, 2 is minimum 3 is enough